# javascript encapsulation - any way to access a private member given instance?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to access a private member in javascript given an instance variable?  For example,

```
function class Foo() {
   var x=12;
   // some other stuff
}
F = new Foo();
// how to get/set F.x?
```

Update: as a twist, suppose that the class has a privileged method.  Is it possible to hijack that privileged method to access a private member?

```
function class Foo() {
   var x=12, y=0;
   this.bar = function(){ y=y+1; }
}
F = new Foo();
// can I modify Foo.bar to access F.x?
```

Comment: Purely as an _academic notion_ you can use `eval` to gain access to local closure scope. We do not do this in real code. There is no `F.x` If you want `F.x` then set `this.x`. You can emulate something like this but it would be horribly over engineered.

Comment: This is not event valid JavaScript code. There is no `class` keyword.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need a [privileged method](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) to get/set the value of `x`:

```
function Foo() {
    var x = 12;
    this.getX = function() { return x; };
    this.setX = function(v) { x = v; };
}

var f = new Foo(),
    g = new Foo();

f.getX(); // returns 12
g.getX(); // returns 12

f.setX(24);

f.getX(); // returns 12
g.getX(); // returns 24

g.setX(24); 

f.getX(); // returns 24
g.getX(); // returns 24
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/j7VtF/

Comment: Can I decorate the class instance to dynamically add a privileged method?

Comment: @Andrew No. Once the constructor function (`Foo`) has created the instance object, the `x` variable is lost - it only existed **during** the execution of the constructor function.

Comment: @Andrew ... unless a nested function survived the constructor call (like `getX` in my example). In that case, this nested function has access to the variable `x`, but you cannot give access to this variable to a function that you create after the constructor call has ended.

Comment: @Sime ... can I decorate a nested, public function to access the private variable?  For instance, as in the updated class example I posted?

Comment: @Andrew No. The nested function `bar` is created during the constructor call and is sealed permanently. You cannot update that function's body subsequently.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this if you **really** wanted access like that, but I ***really*** don't recommend it:

```
function Foo() {
     var x = 12;
     this.runContext = function(f) {
          return eval(f);
     };
}

var f = new Foo();
f.runContext('alert(x);');
```

Comment: That's why I ***really*** don't recommend it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can write your code in a certain pattern to achieve this.

I will demonstrate with help of [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) to demonstrate.

```
function Construct() {
    this.foo = "foo";
    this._private = "bar";

    this.method = function() {
        return 42;
    };

    this._privateMethod = function() {
        return "secret";
    };

    var that = this;
    var inject = function(name, f) {
        this[name] = _.bind(f, that);
    };

    _.bindAll(this);

    return {
        "foo": this.foo,
        "method": this.method,
        "inject": inject
    };
}

var c = new Construct();
console.log(c.foo); // foo
console.log(c.method()); // 42
c.inject("foo", function() {
    console.log(this._private);
    console.log(this._privateMethod());
});
c.foo(); // bar, secret
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/2pwkg/4/)

Basically here you have two objects. Your real object and a proxy object you pass to the client. The proxy can not access the real state apart from going through the proxy methods and variables.

But it does have an inject method which allows you to inject a method onto the real object from the proxy

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the variable `x` is local to the constructor and its value is not retained once that function is out of scope.  However you can assign the value to a named property of the object, such as:

```
var Foo = function() {
  this.x = 12;
}
var f = new Foo();
f.x; // => 12
f.x = 123; // => 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Private members in javascript are attached to the object, but they are not accessible to the outside, nor are they accessible to the object's own public methods. They are accessible to private methods. Private methods are inner functions of the constructor.

You need a public function, which access the private inner function that ultimately accesses private member.

Ref: [Better way to access private members in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041988/better-way-to-access-private-members-in-javascript)

Comment: They are attached to the constructor function scope not the object.